# Email Deliverability - how to change it programatically?

Tags: email, sandbox, sandbox-refresh, deliverability

In all new sandboxes "Email Deliverability" is set to "System Email Only".  I am writing a SandboxPostCopy class to run for all new sandboxes, and want to use that class to change deliverability to "All Email".  Is that possible to do using apex, or can only be done manually?

Comment: I see you've already found [this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009eVjIAI) and also [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cHBEAA2). You've done your research, at least. You should post these links in your question so that much is clear. About all we can do is vote on the Idea ourselves.